# Any decent NPMs to get AWS Cognito Authentication working with Node.js/Express?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-cognito

Might just be that I'm getting documentation fatigue (going through the rabbit hole that is the AWS docs)...but I'm not finding any turnkey NPM/examples to Authenticate Users against AWS Cognito, in Node.js/Express.  I've seen quite a few examples but all either bomb out, are incomplete/vague or require duct tape and bubble gum (pollyfill, web packs, switching to React) or suggest handling all in client (rather than Node backend/routing).

I've also tried using the Cognito Application UI for login, but haven't yet seen how to parse the tokens, etc in order to validate session from screen to screen.

NOTE: i'm still early in my diving into Cognito...but wondering if anyone has come across (or built) any NPMs that might make this less of a headache.

thx.